# HTML text input not showing text field

Tags: html, css

HTML/CSS beginner here, trying to create an input field for users to enter their email address. My form is not displaying a border around the empty text field, making it difficult for users to know that they should enter their email address. However, you can click the field and enter text with no problem.

```
<p>Connect with us to view our sweet video!</p>
    <div class="form_email">
        <form method="post" action="mailto:youremail@youremail.com" >
        Email Address:
            <input type="text" size="35" maxlength="100" 
             value="your_email@domain.com"> 
        </form>
```

This is just a snippet of the code. I think the CSS is styling the text field in some way that is making it invisible. My problem is that I don't know what to look for in the CSS (several thousand lines of code).

Any and all help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should read [The Mythical Mailto](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html)

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](http://jsbin.com/cozibequmo/1/edit?html,output). It must be caused by code you haven't included in your question.

Comment: In your CSS, look for any selector that contains `.form_email` and/or `input` and look for something like `border: none` as a property.

Comment: Inspect the input with your browser's dev tools - Chrome, for example, will show you the computed styles for the element - usually including the lines of CSS responsible for each style.

Answer (score 0):

Search for example:

```
input { border: 0; /* or none */ }
```

You can debug with chrome debug tool https://developer.chrome.com/devtools to see the real css..